# C++20 contracts and unused variables

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Apologies if this has been covered elsewhere.  One of my frustrations has been that whenever I'm trying to check a post-condition of calling a function, I often must decorate the return variable as unused to avoid compiler warnings:

```cpp
auto const count [[maybe_unused]] = some_map.erase(some_key);
assert(count == 1);
```

The reason for the attribute is clear--`assert` is a preprocessor macro that either expands to a no-op if `NDEBUG` is set, or actually evaluates the expression if `NDEBUG` is not set.  In the former case, `count` is technically not used, hence the compiler warning.

With the introduction of contracts in C++20, will the `count` variable still be considered unused?  In other words, will I be able to do:

```cpp
auto const count = some_map.erase(some_key); // no attribute
[[assert: count == 1]];
```

or will I have to do something ugly like:

```cpp
auto const count [[maybe_unused]] = some_map.erase(some_key);
[[assert: count == 1]];
```

Or is this implementation-defined behavior?

Comment: [gcc doesn't warn here](https://godbolt.org/z/87Wplc).

Comment: @Barry Thanks.  Is there anywhere in the current C++ standard, or in the contracts proposal(s) that addresses when a variable is considered unused?

Comment: Pretty sure no to the former. And there's a million contracts-related proposals, so... shrug.

Comment: Warnings are entirely QoI. That said, I don't see how any high-quality implementations would warn here.

Comment: Note that contracts got pulled from C++20 for want of agreement on what options and settings to supply.  A similar feature is likely to reappear later.

Comment: @DavisHerring, Arrrgh, thanks, I've been googling for an hour in vain what I'm doing wrong so neither MSVC nor GCC are willing to accept them (even with c++23), so it must be me, apparently... Now I know that the entire internet has been silent about this because of the guilt. :) (BTW, this was one major red herring: https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/cppreference2018/en/cpp/language/attributes/contract.html -- an innocent-looking search result, esp. as Google doesn't show the full URL. :) )

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn’t define [used](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.unused) at all.  That said, a contract assertion is morally equivalent to

```
if(__check_contract<level>())
  if(!condition) __handle_violation(…);
```

and compilers generally do not warn even if a condition for a usage is a [literal `false`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lo3tadvbEXN5BS1c) (because of generated code, among other reasons).  So you should be fine.